# Extracting variable in YAML from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, yq

I have a YAML file composed of the following:

```
acceleration_matrix:
  # 1ere row: x
  - [20, 0, 0, 15, 15]
  # 2eme row: y
  - [0, 15, 0, 0, 0]
  # 3eme row: z
  - [0, 0, 30, 15, -15]
  # 4eme row: repere de l'acceleration
  - [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  # 5eme row: loadcase_id
  - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to extract the last value of the last row (in this case, `5`) unsing a shell script.
Using [this article](https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script), I coded:

```
#!/bin/bash

function parse_yaml {
   local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\):|\1|" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;
      for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
      if (length($3) > 0) {
         vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
         printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
      }
   }'
}

parse_yaml nastran_acceleration_matrix.yml

echo $acceleration_matrix
```

But as I am a newbie in shell, I can't find how to extract the values.
What I would want is simply something like :

```
set number_load_case = ### acceleration_matrix[-1,-1] ### (I'm more used to coding in python thus the -1 aka last row/column)
```

Could anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Which specific_ program named `yq` are you using? One is a wrapper around jq and uses standard jq syntax; the other is its own independently-developed thing, with its own language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a proper parser such as [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). Your task (last value of last element of `acceleration_matrix`) then becomes as simple as

```sh
yq eval '.acceleration_matrix[-1][-1]' nastran_acceleration_matrix.yml
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I cannot use yq as I call the script from another software to which I cannot add librairies...

Comment: I managed to install it and call it remotly so your command works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Install shyaml

```
 $ pip install shyaml      ## installation

conda env create -f environment.yml -n cat test.yaml | shyaml get-value conda_env_name
```

You can try above command after installing shyaml.

If this won't work for you, then you can try **'jq'** and **'yq'** in bash script which will parse your yaml to json and then you can read the values from JSON, after which you can run your command from bash itself.

Comment: Thanks. The current setup does not allow me to install any pip packages before creating a conda. So is it possible to achieve this using `sed/grep/awk`?

Comment: I am just aware that sed commands are used for file operation, but never got to work on it. I am sure about bash script. With bash you can achieve this easily. There you don't need to install any package.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea based **solely** on OP's sample input:

```
$ awk -F'[] ]' '{lastid=$(NF-1)} END {print lastid}' test.yaml
5
```

Where:

- `-F'[] ]'` - set input field delimiter as `<space>` or `]`
- `lastid=$(NF-1)` - keep track of next to last field
- `END {print lastid}` - print the last 'next to last field' we saved
- net result: scan entire file, saving next to last field as we progress, and at the end of the file we print/output the last 'next to last' field we captured

To store in a `bash` variable:

```
$ number_load_case=$(awk -F'[] ]' '{lastid=$(NF-1)} END {print lastid}' test.yaml)
$ echo "${number_load_case}"
5
```

**NOTES:**

- this will obviously generate an incorrect result if the input is not formatted **exactly** as in OPs sample (eg, if last line is blank then `awk` will fail with error: `fatal: attempt to access field -1`)
- as already mentioned something like `yq` would be better suited to this problem, especially if formatting is not as 'pretty' as in OP's sample
- for less 'pretty' formatting, and the inability to use something like `yq`, a more robust parser could be written (eg, in `awk`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Indeed, as this will be implemented for the user to modify the yaml, I'm a bit scared that one does more than just change the correct value and messes up the whole workflow (in which the code will be implemented), but thank you very much!